# Quadratic inequality with Modulus of a Linear Equation : Solution Verification & Clarification Needed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, quadratics, absolute-value

$x^2-|5x-3|-x<2$

For this problem I took two cases where in one case $5x-3 \geq 0$ and in second case $5x-3 \lt 0$.

$1st$ Case  when $5x-3 \geq 0$ :-

For this case I got the solution set as $x \in [0.6,3+2\sqrt{2}]$.

$2nd$ Case  when $5x-3 \lt 0$ :-

For this case I got the solution set as $x \in [-5,0.6]$.

Upon combining both the cases I am getting the solution set as $x \in [-5,3+2\sqrt{2}]$ but in the answer that has been provided for this problem is not including the points and thus the answer given is $x \in (-5,3+2\sqrt{2})$.

What am I doing wrong here that is making my endpoints of the solution inclusive whereas the the solution set provided has got endpoints exclusive. Please help me on this !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me forcus on when $5x-3<0$, we have $x < \frac35$ and

$$x^2-|5x-3|-x<2$$

becomes

$$x^2-(3-5x)-x<2$$

$$x^2+4x-5<0$$

$$(x+5)(x-1)<0$$

Hence we have $-5 < x < 1$ and $x < \frac35$, hence taking intersection, we have $-5<x < \frac35$.

To answer the question, why did we exclude $x=-5$, consider $(x+5)(x-1)<0$, if we substute $x=5$ inside, we get $0<0$ which is not true.

---

If $5x-3 \ge 0$, we have $x \ge \frac35$ and

$$x^2-|5x-3|-x < 2$$

becomes

$$x^2-5x+3-x < 2$$

$$x^2-6x+1 < 0$$

$$\frac{6-\sqrt{36-4}}{2} < x < \frac{6+\sqrt{36-4}}{2} $$

$$3-2\sqrt2< x < 3+2\sqrt2 $$

Taking intersection with $x \ge \frac35$, we have

$$\frac35 \le x < 3+2\sqrt2$$

---

Taking union, we have $-5 < x < 3+2\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $x^2-|5x-3|-x<2$

when  5x−3≥0, $x^2-6x+1<0$,   x $\in$ [0.6,3+2$\sqrt2$)

when  5x−3$\leq$0, $x^2+4x-5<0$, $(x-1)(x+5)<0$,  x $\in$ (-5,0.6] (You should not include 5 in this case.)

So the answer is x $\in$ (-5,3+2$\sqrt2$).

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain why have you not included $3+2\sqrt2$ in x $\in [0.6,3+2\sqrt2)?$ As per my understanding $3+2\sqrt2$ comes under the the range for the solution of 5x−3≥0?